# How to find words around a particular word in a file

Tags: c++

I have a big file in my results. I want to look for words around a specific word in this file.
For example, if I have a file like this:
I 
am
going
home
they
are
going 
school
sam
is 
going
to
lunch

How can I get words before and after "going" and save it in a hash using C++.

Comment: He's probably thinking of an unordered_map

Comment: hash table is used to store values

Answer (score 2):

You can just read the file word by word, always keeping N words as context. You can store the context in a [`std::deque`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/deque) which allows a rolling context

```
const int N = 10;
std::deque<std::string> words_before, words_after;
std::string current_word, w;

// prefetch words before and after
for (int i = 0; i < N; ++i) {
    std::cin >> w;
    words_before.push_back(w);
}

std::cin >> current_word;

for (int i = 0; i < N - 1; ++i) {
    std::cin >> w;
    words_after.push_back(w);
}

// now process the words and keep reading
while (std::cin >> w) {
    words_after.push_back(w);
    // save current_word with the words around words_before, words_after
    words_before.pop_front();
    words_before.push_back(current_word);
    current_word = words_after.front();
    words_after.pop_front();
}
```

Comment: This is a good answer, but technically this wouldn't work for his question. Since there is more than one word between the two 'going's

Comment: I have to extract the context of plus/minus 10 words around a particular word

Comment: @MementoMori Your comment is reasonable. I updated my answer.

Comment: @user2162685 Then I misunderstood your question and this approach won't work for you.

Comment: @user2162685 I updated my answer. This is now more wordy, but I hope, you get the idea.

Comment: @OlafDietsche Thank you for your answer. I got an idea. I will try to implement this.